# How to move a window, or switch, to another virtual desktop using the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, autohotkey, virtual-desktop

Is there a way to achieve this using Autohotkey if there is no native functionality for it?

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to another desktop by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>, and create a new one with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

As far as I know, there's no shortcut to move a window to another virtual desktop. If you really want to avoid using the mouse you can do:

- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to open Task View
- Arrow keys to select window to be moved
- <kbd>Context key</kbd> to open the context menu for that window
- Select a `Move To Desktop` option

I doubt existing third-party utilities will help for this, since it's a new feature in the windows "internals". A potential solution would be a small application or powershell script that would have access (through the Windows API) to control this, but I haven't come across anything yet.